# Reboot nodes from salt scheduler randomly

Tags: salt-stack

I have a task to reboot machines one by one, with let say 1 hour interval between reboot of machine 1 and machine 2, it can be some reasonable amount of machines, but still not 1 or 2. The interval between reboots should be configurable, or even random, like splay. 
I've searched documentation and could not find anything beautiful for this task.

So far I could made up solution with batch 1, and run every hour from cron, but maybe there is some better solution available?

The main problem is how to make sure only one machine is rebooting at the moment.